# Error: unable to connect to cassandra server. Unconfigured table

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cql3

I am trying to connect to cassandra, which is running on local desktop, via cassandra-driver for python using this simple code.

```
 from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
 cluster = Cluster()
 session = cluster.connect()
```

and getting this error: ***NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': InvalidRequest(u'code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table schema_keyspaces"',)})***

From the logs of cassandra, I see how it does establish connection, but it gets this errors:

```
DEBUG 05:51:00 Responding: ERROR INVALID: unconfigured table schema_columnfamilies, v=4
DEBUG 05:51:00 Responding: ERROR INVALID: unconfigured table schema_usertypes, v=4
DEBUG 05:51:00 Responding: ERROR INVALID: unconfigured table schema_columns, v=4
DEBUG 05:51:00 Responding: ERROR INVALID: unconfigured table schema_functions, v=4
DEBUG 05:51:00 Responding: ERROR INVALID: unconfigured table schema_aggregates, v=4
DEBUG 05:51:00 Responding: ERROR INVALID: unconfigured table schema_triggers, v=4
```

Any help to solve this problem with unconfigured tables will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you possibly using the driver to connect to Cassandra 3.0.0-alpha1? If so, you'd need to be running the driver installed from this commit:

https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/tree/1a480f196ade42798596f5257d2cbeffcadf154f

Alternatively:

- If you're just experimenting, the released drivers as of today work with all Cassandra versions 1.2 - 2.2.0
- <del>DataStax is readying a 3.0.0a1 version of the driver for use with Cassandra 3.0.0-alpha1, which will be available in pypi soon.</del>
- install the 3.0.0 alpha version of the driver as follows:

  pip install --pre cassandra-driver

  pip install --pre --upgrade cassandra-driver

Comment: Thank you! I downgraded cassandra.

Comment: nice , works for me too. maybe you need to install packages libev4 libev-dev to support libev.

Answer (score 0):

This thread came up when I had the same error message and searched for info, but the answers given didn't help me. I found the issue eventually. I'm running Cassandra 3.6, and the cassandra-driver currently available is version 3.4.1.

However, for some reason I had version 2.2.0 of cassandra-driver installed. I understand the table schema_keyspaces has been renamed/moved in later versions, so that explains why the old driver didn't get the results it expected and bailed out.